# Howto use git with a server?

Tags: git

I have a server (Linux, Debian) and my client (Windows). Currently I just copy my files over ssh to the server. Now I want to be cool and use git.

I am trying this for a long time now and I am not sure what my question is. I created repositories on server and client. Commited my files but failed to push/pull/clone with IDE/GUI/console. Finally I managed to clone from command line. Just to find out that push does still not work.

Do I need a bare repository? Looks like bare repositories don't have any files so I need two repositories an my server? Do I have to make a manual checkout on the server every time? I thought I can just push it there...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Error messages? A bare repository is generally used as a central repository for a team of developers.
A comment aside: Do you intend to manage a software project with git or do you want to synchronize data, including binary data, with your server?

Comment: alternatively you could set up a private GITHUB account and let THEM worry about managing the repository.

Comment: Could you post the error messages that you get? "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful information.

Comment: What error messages should I post for my questions: Do I need a bare repository? Looks like bare repositories don't have any files so I need two repositories an my server? Do I have to make a manual checkout on the server every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git community documentation extensively explains how to use a remote repository over ssh and how to set one up you should read the documentation.

http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_private_repository.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correctly added "remote" if not then use "git add remote" command. Another possibility is that ssh keys. Make sure you have correctly configured ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to push in a non-bare repository in specific situations: A non-bare repository has always a working copy to work on. Let's assume the working copy is based on master. If you now want to push into master from another repository, git cannot push theses changes into the master, because the working copy bases on it.

That's why you should use a bare repository:
A bare repository is very small and easy to use, because you can push in it without any merging and checkout.